# How were old-style Feynman diagrams drawn before software?

Tags: soft-question, feynman-diagrams, history

I wasn't sure where to put this question as it's not directly about physics, but before software to draw them was around how were Feynman diagrams drawn in papers? For example ones that look like,
[image]

Comment: Once upon a time, labs (university, national lab, corporate) had graphic artists on staff to prepare publication-quality figures. When I started grad school in the mid-80s the department was down to having only a professional photographer on staff, who still had lots of work because of all the (optical/electron) microscopy going on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question (v2) because it is not really about physics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Our physics department had  draughtsmen who drew them on "vellum" with Rotring drawing pens or something similar, and templates. The  author produced a sketch and the professional  made them publishable.

The draughting office charged a fee to your research grant, so drawing software saved us money, but at the same time made the draughtsman unemployed.

Comment: A search on Amazon for "Technical Drawing Supplies" will yield examples of some of the tools that they traditionally used.